# Trying to schedule a meeting using the Zoom API

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, web-applications, zoom-sdk

I'm building a website with Node.js, Express.js, and Mongodb, and I'm trying to make it so users can schedule a Zoom meeting inside the website. I just want it to schedule, then return the link to join.

[Here](https://marketplace.zoom.us/docs/guides/zoom-rooms/zoom-rooms-api#schedule) is a page in the documentation that I found, but I'm not sure where to even start with it. I've been searching for a LONG time now, but I'm stumped.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to create a zoom meeting programmatically in your application, you have to first register your app with Zoom and then you will get API Key and Secret Key. These two keys will be used in your program to interact with Zoom API. You can find the steps and code in Node Js to interact with zoom in below blogs:

https://jksnu.blogspot.com/2021/07/how-to-manage-zoom-meeting.html

https://jksnu.blogspot.com/2021/07/how-to-manage-zoom-meeting_18.html

Comment: I don't know if you are the author of the post or not, but thanks a lot. It saved me a lot of time by getting right to the point of PO use case

Comment: Yes. I am the author of this post. Actually, I had invested good amount of time to understand the steps mentioned in the blog. So, I thought to put it in a blog for other's use

Answer (score 0):

We create meetings by this api:

route: `/users/{userId}/meetings`

docs: https://marketplace.zoom.us/docs/api-reference/zoom-api/meetings/meetingcreate